# Wkhtmltopdf delay time for bokeh plots

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, bokeh

To save my bokeh plots as a png-image, I render them by commmand-line with the tool `wkhtmltoimage` with this command:

```
call([pathName+"\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltoimage", ["--crop-y 120"],name ,saveAs])
```

This is working fine for not-so-big plots. But for larger ones (that take some time until they are beeing displayed in my browser) it does not work (it creates an empty 0 KB png). Is there a way to tell the wkhtmltoimage-app to wait a bit longer? I assume it terminates because the plot is not responding, but not sure.

I am running Windows 7, the error occurs both on 32 and 64 bit systems.

Answer (score 0):

Based on their documentation (http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt), it looks like you should try the `--javascript-delay <msec>` option.